# How to make Q queries with models with foreign keys?

Tags: django, django-models, django-q

my model is defined like this:

```
class Model2(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = ...

class Model1(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    model2 = models.ForeignKey(Model2, to_field='id', db_column='model2')
```

The problem is I do not know how to make OR queries with queryset.

```
qs = Model1.objects.filter(Q(model2.id__icontains=search) | Q(id__icontains=search))
```

I get

> keyword can't be an expression

So the question is how can I reference to the field of the related model in Q queries? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
qs = Model1.objects.filter(Q(model2__id=search) | Q(id=search))
```

I would revisit the implementation if you are looking for `id__icontains`

If you search for 1, then it would look for `1`, `11`, `121`, `166`..., (any id with 1 in it) which is probably not what you want.

To specifically point out your error,

```
Q(model2.id__icontains=search)
```

should be

```
Q(model2__id__icontains=search)
```